# Sonar and Datanucleus

Tags: java, jdo, sonarqube, datanucleus

What are the best practices if we want sonar to ignore the critical violations related to "Performance - Private method is never called » Private method xxx.xxx.xxx.jdoXXX... is never called" UPM_UNCALLED_PRIVATE_METHOD for the private fields annotated with the DataNucleus @Persistent ?

We already tried the tag //NOSONAR and @SuppressWarnings("all")

Comment: can you edit the quality profile and just ignore the rule there?

Answer (score 1):

After tangling with a similar issue from a different annotation, it appears you must put the NOSONAR tag on both the method declaration line as well as the first line of the method itself:

```
private void sampleMethod() { // NOSONAR
    doSomething(); // NOSONAR
}
```

Hope that helps.